# msbuild clcompile specification? (Mapping of switches to XML properties)

Tags: xml, msbuild, tags, specifications

Is there a document that maps the command line switches to the MSbuild properties for a Visual C++ project? The closest I've got is found in the Microsoft.CL.common props file that is shipped with MSBuild. However it is not complete for what I am looking for.

I am trying to reverse engineer a legacy build system!

Here is an example of the MSBuild xml properties that I need to know what the command line switches would map to:

```
<ClCompile>
<AssemblerOutput>NoListing</AssemblerOutput>
<AssemblerListingLocation>$(IntDir)</AssemblerListingLocation>
<UndefineAllPreprocessorDefinition></UndefineAllPreprocessorDefinition>
<BrowseInformation>false</BrowseInformation>
<BrowseInformationFile>$(IntDir)</BrowseInformationFile>
<BasicRuntimeChecks>Default</BasicRuntimeChecks>
<CompileAs>Default</CompileAs>
<DisableLanguageExtensions>false</DisableLanguageExtensions>
<ErrorReporting>Prompt</ErrorReporting>
<ErrorReporting>Queue</ErrorReporting>
<ExpandAttributedSource>false</ExpandAttributedSource>
<ExceptionHandling>Sync</ExceptionHandling>
<EnableFiberSafeOptimizations>false</EnableFiberSafeOptimizations>
<EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>NotSet</EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>
<FloatingPointModel>Precise</FloatingPointModel>
</ClCompile>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can see all the property pages and configuration options by right clicking your project and selecting Properties.**

Clicking on a property gives the command line switch to pass in and a brief description.

[image: Property Page config options and descriptions]

**Here is a link to all the compiler switches and what they do:**

[Compiler Options Listed Alphabetically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

If you want the XML file that describes all the switches and properties then you can find it on your local computer by browsing to this directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\1033
```

Your location may vary slightly. Here you will find all the xml property files.

**Take a look at the CL.xml file.**

**Additional info:**
[VCCLCompilerTool Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.VCCLCompilerTool_properties.aspx)

You can also reference this link that exposes all the VCCL compiler properties. The documentation is a little better.

[How to: Integrate Custom Tools into the Project Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770593.aspx)

Comment: Ideal, the cl.xml file (and friends) contains exactly the information required.

Answer (score 4):

The msbuild task ultimately invoked for compilation is `CL`. Hence the documentation can be found when looking for `msbuild CL task`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/cl-task

Likewise there is the `LINK` task, the `LIB` task and so on. These might also be of interest for you: compiler options alone might not be enough.

Comment: Just an update... "for the latest documentation on Visual Studio 2017, see [CL Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/cl-task) on learn.microsoft.com". Looks like the same info though I like the styles used better on this latest web page.